# How do I navigate back?

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, mocha.js

I m trying to navigate back on google page. I am using selenium webdriver with javascript and mocha framework: [screen capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cv8Ei.png).

I have tried driver.navigate().back() but it seems like it does not work. does any one know. thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try `window.history.back();`

You can read more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_his_back.asp)

Comment: says it " window is not defined"

Comment: Are you running it with node file.js?

Comment: running it on mocha using node js

Comment: I gave you the answer for the browser version. You need HTML for that one.

Comment: I am not a developer sir.I am trying to learn mocha framework. I am a tester.

Comment: I dont have access to html files

Comment: You don't have to call me sir. You need html for the answer that I gave to you.

Comment: Oh then you can maybe ask your employee or the developer for the files.

Comment: ok. I understand. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: You are very welcome and good luck on your project!

Answer (score 0):

check out history.back() : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/back

```js
document.getElementById('go-back').addEventListener('click', () => {
  history.back();
});
```

```html
<button id="go-back">Go back!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using selenium according to [docs](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver_exports_Navigation.html#back) you can use `this.back()`